# Search API view - Displaying items that doesn't meet Facets criteria

Tags: views, search

I have a search api view where I display houses with number of bedrooms in each of the house, and I'm using facet api to create filter so that for example if I would click on "2" it would only display houses that have only 2 bedrooms in it.

But I would also like to below this view (or as part of this view) display other results that doesn't meet the criteria (and that are filtered out by facets) and I'm really stuck with how this can be done.

In addition I only want it to happen with "Bedrooms" but not with "Bathrooms".

I hope someone can help I'm really stuck with this issue!

** small update 26.09.2015 **

I'm trying to achieve that now by combining two views together using views attachment and having "views negate" filter to work on values provided by exposed filter.. so far no luck.

And views attachments are being displayed UNDER pagination, instead of after the normal results which is not what I ideally would want to have.

After that I'm planning to change the normal exposed filter into BEF with links and style them as facets...

Comment: What you're looking for is at odds with how filtering works. Filters are there to make sure that the entire result _doesn't_ get returned along with the required results. You're talking about a client-side filter, which would have to load every possible result, every time, and then filter that massive list rather than getting the narrower list to begin with.

Comment: I think, I don't want to filter out results... at all I just want the "correct" ones to be at the top, instead of the filtering out the ones that doesn't meet criteria.  I understand that in some situations my approach may not be the correct one, but this is what I'm trying to achieve and I wonder how to achieve that. If you have any suggestions please let me know.

Answer (score -1):

Might be wrong place, but my query is related to retrieving improper data. I am using facet to filter the result its working fine. But if I use solr slop to retrive data all the  record are proper and then try to filter the record using another facet Sector then the result displayed in location facet is improper. e.g

Initially search for England, it retrieves all data of England record include location, Sector Cont type data.Location details are displayed in location facet block. But when I do deep filter using Sector facet(sector records are within location searched I.e. England) I get records from Scotland location too.. Scotland location is listed in the location facet along with England. Not knowing what is going wrong afteer using Solr slop as without it all the data retrieved is proper.